# Flask url_for() pass multiple parameters but only show one in the blueprint route?

Tags: flask

I am new to Flasks and Jinja templates.  I am trying to pass two parameters from my html file to a blueprint route.  I am passing the unique ID that I can use to query the database and a location field.  I only want the location field to show up in the url.

```
@trips_blueprint.route('/mytrips/<selected_trip_location>',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def show_details(selected_trip_location, selected_trip_id):
    selected_trip = Trip.query.filter_by(id=selected_trip_id)

    return render_template('trip_detail.html')
```

```
  <a href="{{url_for('trips.show_details', selected_trip_location=mytrip.location, selected_trip_id=mytrip.id)}}">
```

When I run this, it says TypeError: show_details() missing 1 required positional argument: 'selected_trip_id'

Any ideas how I can get around that and not display the unique id in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flask documentation says the following for `url_for`:

> Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are
> appended to the generated URL as query arguments.

Therefore, `selected_trip_id` will be a query argument in the generated URL (not a parameter sent to `show_details`).

If you don't want `selected_trip_id` to show in the URL, you have to send it in a POST request, as follows:

1. Remove `selected_trip_id` from the parameters of the view function `show_details` (as this expects `selected_trip_id` to be included in the URL).
2. Include the following code in your HTML:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('trips.show_details', selected_trip_location=mytrip.location) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_trip_id" value="{{ mytrip.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

3. Receive `selected_trip_id` in your view function:

```py
@trips_blueprint.route('/mytrips/<selected_trip_location>', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def show_details(selected_trip_location):
    
    if request.method == "POST":

        selected_trip_id = request.form.get("selected_trip_id")
        selected_trip = Trip.query.filter_by(id=selected_trip_id)

    ...
```